# Control panel search on frontend

Tags: craft3

How difficult would it be to replicate the control panel search on the frontend of a Craft site? I currently have a standard Craft search as shown in the documentation but it's a little slow as I have a large amount of entries.

Comment: Can you share the code you currently have for your search form/results?

Comment: I just use a search similar to what's shown in the documentation. I actually created a [seperate post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/33939/optimising-search-query) a few months ago that has some code.